# Classify error/answer type

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, answers, duplicate-questions

Wouldn't it be helpful for the users to be able to tag the accepted answer in a restricted number of categories?
E.g.:

- **Providing resources** (SO or external) [when the answer gives more resources which are actually interesting and not easy to find through search engines or other reasons]
- **Best Practice** [when the answers explains how to improve an already running ]
- **Common error** [fix of a common error which is anyway interesting to be shown]
- **Workaround** [when the answers aims to give a solution to a well-known problem which can't be properly fixed].

I believe this could improve the experience of finding the 'Right answer', avoiding many of the duplicate questions out there.

**Update 1**

To avoid misunderstandings of the meaning of this feature it may be:

- enabled only for experienced users (based on reputation)
- forcing only one tag (or more complex exclusion tag policy)

More over the tag may not necessary be set by the *requesting OP*, it could be also be set by the *answering OP*. This could also improve the "Accepting answer" process (e.g. the OP is looking for a best practice or common error, but all the answers are workarounds...)

Comment: Two of those categories (providing resources and best practices) are explicitly off-topic. I don't think we want to encourage off-topic questions by tagging answers with those categories.

Comment: I do not think some of the categories are explicitly off topic, I think you should at least motivate your answer so that I can learn something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst a number of experienced users may understand the situations that a questioner could tag accepted answers using the categories you have suggested (or any other), many users asking questions don't even realise you can accept an answer in the first place.

You could find that a feature such as this could start a lot of "tag in all the accept categories" requests from answerers, in the same way they request the OP to mark an answer as accepted now. Also, an OP's judgement of what meets the criteria will be very different to another OP. Would *suggested edits* for these tags be allowed?

I think this would cause more problems than it would solve. Good thought, but I don't believe it to be workable.

Comment: I've edited the question to improve the method thanks to your answer. Obviously also suggested edits may be allowed, as an option.